# In reStructuredText, how do I use emphasis and superscript at the same time?

Tags: restructuredtext

The following piece of reStructuredText does not give the result I expect.

```
*:sup:`superscript`*
```

Expected result: *<sup>superscript</sup>*

Actual result: *:sup:`superscript`*

The reason why it is happening is clear (reST text roles cannot be nested), however how can I obtain the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in [a FAQ](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible), this is not currently possible without using the `raw` directive or without using a custom, ad-hoc directive.

Comment: "...on the to-do list... and hopefully will be part of the reStructuredText parser soon", as of [2004-06-14](https://github.com/tony/docutils/commit/5db39c158f316a28fb9ff941a9737e22b68d2f41). Patience is a virtue :).

Answer (score 4):

You can use substitution:

```
The chemical formula for pure water is |H2O|.

.. |H2O| replace:: H\ :sub:`2`\ O
```

See the [reStructuredText spec](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) for further information on [character-level markup](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup) and the [substitution](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-references) mechanism.

Comment: Note also the use of surrounding escaped spaces, also mentioned in the documentation, that are required for correct parsing of the directive, and also demonstrated (but not explicitly mentioned) in this example.